# Adding and removing tkinter frames - keeping track of instances

Tags: python, class, tkinter, instance

I'm trying to create a bunch of sub-frames in a Tkinter GUI, each containing some user input variables that I will need to be able to get at later via a unique ID for each sub-frame. I need to be able to add and delete sub-frames at will, and have them ID'd in a sensible order (integers counting up from 1, at the moment)

Three questions really:

1) Specifically, why does the Label widget showing the title of each frame not display? (this is probably something silly...)

2) Specifically, why does it sometimes take two presses of the add or remove button to add or remove a frame?

3) Generally: is there a better way to approach this? In the sense of keeping track of the frame instances. They're in a list now... I started out with a dict earlier but it was harder to work with... are there better suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class AllInstances(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.master_frame = Frame(self)
        self.master_frame.grid()
        self.all_instances = []

root = AllInstances()

class OneInstance():
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = len(root.all_instances) + 1

        var1 = StringVar()
        var2 = StringVar()
        var3 = StringVar()

        self.sub_frame = Frame(root.master_frame)
        self.sub_frame.grid(column = self.number, row = 0)

        titletext = StringVar()
        titletext.set('%s %s' % ('Frame', self.number))
        print(titletext.get())
        title = Label(self.sub_frame, textvariable = titletext)
        title.grid() #work out why this label does not display!

        uservar1 = Entry(self.sub_frame, textvariable = var1)
        uservar1.grid()
        uservar2 = Entry(self.sub_frame, textvariable = var2)
        uservar2.grid()
        uservar3 = Entry(self.sub_frame, textvariable = var3)
        uservar3.grid()
        #etc etc

        add_button = Button(self.sub_frame, text = 'Add', command = lambda: Create())
        add_button.grid()

        def RemoveInstance(self):
            if len(root.all_instances) > 1:
                root.all_instances.remove(self)
                self.sub_frame.destroy()

                for instance in root.all_instances:
                    instance.number = (root.all_instances.index(instance) + 1)
            else:
                pass

        remove_button = Button(self.sub_frame, text = 'Remove', command = lambda: RemoveInstance(self))
        remove_button.grid()

        root.all_instances.append(self)

def Create():
    OneInstance()

Create()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Make `AllInstances` inherit from `Frame` (and rename to something like "FrameGroup"). It then becomes a "megawidget", with the subframes being children that it can directly control.
2. Make your subframe a subclass of `Frame` (and call it "Subframe"). This is also a "megawidget", and it needs to be loosly coupled to its parent (ie: it shouldn't know about `root.all_instances`
3. Have your add and remove buttons call methods on the FrameGroup object.

I also recommend *not* doing a global import. Since you're using both ttk and tkinter, one will overwrite the other depending on which order you order the import statements.

Here's a working example with those modifications:

```
import tkinter as tk

class FrameGroup(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.all_instances = []
        self.counter = 0

    def Add(self):
        self.counter += 1
        name = "Frame %s" % self.counter 
        subframe = Subframe(self, name=name)
        subframe.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.all_instances.append(subframe)

    def Remove(self, instance):
        # don't allow the user to destroy the last item
        if len(self.all_instances) > 1:
            index = self.all_instances.index(instance)
            subframe = self.all_instances.pop(index)
            subframe.destroy()

    def HowMany(self):
        return len(self.all_instances)

    def ShowMe(self):
        for instance in self.all_instances:
            print(instance.get())

class Subframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e3 = tk.Entry(self)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=name, anchor="center")
        add_button = tk.Button(self, text="Add", command=self.parent.Add)
        remove_button = tk.Button(self, text="Remove", command=lambda: self.parent.Remove(self))

        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.e1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.e2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.e3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        add_button.pack(side="top")
        remove_button.pack(side="top")

    def get(self):
        return (self.e1.get(), self.e2.get(), self.e3.get())

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.master_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.master_frame.grid()
        self.all_instances = FrameGroup(self.master_frame)
        self.all_instances.grid()

        # create the first frame
        self.all_instances.Add()

root = GUI()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I think I can see the logic of how you have restructured it. Your simpler .pack() approach avoids the problem of getting the right column, but consecutive columns and frame names will be necessary for me, so I'll have to look at that again with .grid(). Re: importing ttk and overwriting tkinter - I was happy with that and don't need the clarity of tk.widget or ttk.widget (on the basis that all the widgets I am actually using get overridden and then I can use ttk styles without additional typing) but are there any other downsides of which I should be aware?

Comment: @Tom: pack and grid have nothing to do with the frame names. As for the other downsides, I simply thing it's a best practice not to do global imports. Plus, it makes the code harder to understand when you do global imports. For example, I assumed you were using tkinter buttons and labels, and it wasn't until I was polishing up my answer that I realized that you were depending on ttk imports overriding the tk imports. If you use `ttk.Button` or `tk.Button`, your code is crystal clear which widgets you are using, and clarity should be a high priority goal when writing software.

Comment: @Tom: if you want consecutive column names even when the user deletes a column in the middle, an easy solution is to add a `rename` method to the `Subframe` class, then have your `Remove` function iterate over all of the instances, calling rename with the new names you want for each column.

Comment: @BryanOakley, i have almost a similar problem. However, I created my frames using a function not using class. How can I edit the remove function in my case? Thank you.